# What's a good RSS Importer?

Tags: rss, import, feed

I'm looking for a good RSS importer to use on my WordPress installation. The current one isn't importing images properly, and I don't want to fix it.

It needs to be an automated importer. Where I give it the link to the feed and it auto imports automatically every set interval. It also needs to import into a category, not a page.

I'm currently using FeedWordPress, just so no one suggests that as an option.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) and [Simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) ?.take a look on it. i think these are good one.If you want to activate by plugin means try [RSS Import](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/).